# NATS.io for React Native?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, native, nats.io

I've been trying to add nats.io into a React Native project with Typescript but lots of obstacles appeared, I was wondering if there is a correct way of doing it without modifying node_modules of nats (to change "fs" import to "react-native-fs" for example). Is this even possible to do? Thanks

One of the first problems to appear once I do yarn add nats or nats@latest is the following:

```
**util could not be found within the project.
If you are sure the module exists, try these steps:
 1. Clear watchman watches: watchman watch-del-all
 2. Delete node_modules and run yarn install
 3. Reset Metro's cache: yarn start --reset-cache
 4. Remove the cache: rm -rf /tmp/metro-*
  27 |  */
  28 | if (typeof TextEncoder === "undefined") {
> 29 |     const { TextEncoder, TextDecoder } = require("util");
     |                                                   ^
  30 |     global.TextEncoder = TextEncoder;
  31 |     global.TextDecoder = TextDecoder;
  32 | }**
```

Comment: What version of Node are you using? Current versions of Node have TextEncoder defined in the global space? I am wondering if instead, you should be using nats.ws (WebSockets) as this is just standard browser compliant JavaScript which is likely better supported across devices?

Comment: @AlbertoRicart Thanks for the answer. I'm currently using Node v14.17.1. The thing is I have a NATS server with standard port 4222, my client is in react native (with Typescript) and I want to connect to it. The main problem is that I can't find a way to add the nats client dependency correctly into react native.

Comment: this is why I was suggesting (nats.ws)[https://github.com/nats-io/nats.ws] library - you won't have node specific dependencies there. NATS over websockets uses a standard WebSocket API which is very likely available on different native platforms vs TCP socket that uses the Node API.

Comment: this is why I was suggesting (nats.ws)[https://github.com/nats-io/nats.ws] library - you won't have node specific dependencies there. NATS over websockets uses a standard WebSocket API which is very likely available on different native platforms vs TCP socket that uses the Node API.

Comment: @AlbertoRicart Thanks, I tried using nats.ws but encountered a problem with TextEncoder ReferenceError: Can't find variable: TextEncoder

Comment: @Martin did you find any way around this? Right now I am facing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Try upgrading your node version, 11+ should have it. If not there may be a configuration on your bundler that is preventing you from using it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [nats.ws](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nats.ws) package with a few setup steps described below to utilize nats.io within a React Native app.

### Add polyfill packages

nats.ws depends on some APIs not natively available within the React Native JS runtime. We need to use [polyfills](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Polyfill) to fill in these missing APIs.

Install the required packages in your React Native / Expo project using one of the following commands:

**yarn:**
`yarn add @azure/core-asynciterator-polyfill fastestsmallesttextencoderdecoder nats.ws node-libs-react-native react-native-url-polyfill text-encoding-polyfill`

**npm:**
`npm install @azure/core-asynciterator-polyfill fastestsmallesttextencoderdecoder nats.ws node-libs-react-native react-native-url-polyfill text-encoding-polyfill`

### Modify `metro.config.js`

The following needs to be added to the Metro bundler's configuration file to add Node core modules such as `stream` to the React Native runtime.

```js
// metro.config.js
module.exports = {
resolver: {
extraNodeModules: require('node-libs-react-native'),
    },
    // Add more config here if needed
};
```

### Import polyfills in `App.js`

Import the polyfills in your app's ***starting file*** (`App.js` in my case). This ensures the APIs they provide become available globally within your application's JavaScript context.

```js
import 'react-native-url-polyfill/auto';
import 'text-encoding-polyfill';
import '@azure/core-asynciterator-polyfill'
```

[Example React Native project](https://github.com/thegreatzeus/NATS-WS-React-Native-Example)